# google project quota disabled

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have been making Google drive API requests from my website for a month now, It was working fine . suddenly now there's an error:

```
'{ "error" : "disabled_client", "error_description" : "The OAuth client was disabled." }'
```

When I go into the API console. In the quotas section it says

> Quotas for this project have been disabled. If you've recently deleted
>   and undeleted this project, please contact support. Repeating the
>   delete-undelete step may also help. Click here to contact support.

Can someone Please tell me what the problem is . Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Oauth2? I would contact the support.

Comment: yes Iam using oauth2 . The support team isnt responding to my query.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Is the whole project affected or just Drive SDK?